# Not able to Connect with phpmyadmin on ip address say "67.3.234.45" with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, phpmyadmin

I have created a user with all privileges. Bit confused in selecting Host(currently localhost),

Hibernate setting are.

```
jdbc.driverClassName    = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url                = jdbc:mysql://67.3.234.45:3306/user
jdbc.username           = username
jdbc.password           = password
hibernate.dialect       = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql      = true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto  = update
```

exception is : Updated the question with full exception..

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1038)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:338)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2237)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:219)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
```

Comment: what has phpmyadmin todo with this?

Comment: Please provide the full call stack, with all the "caused by" pieces

Comment: phpmyadmin is installed on server.. my local database works correctly(not phpmyadmin) but not able to connect to sql on server.

Comment: Paste the message in Google, `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`. You are likely to get some hints. The database appears to be unreachable for some unknown reasons.

Comment: phpmyadmin and java program is not on same machine. What changes and how i have to do to make the connection work. Like enable phpmyadmin to accept connection from other machines. I am reading other related question but still not able to figure ot.

Comment: Does the stack trace really stop there? From looking at the source code it should continue with some 'caused by' ...

Answer (score 1):

First: phpmyadmin is a tool for administring databases. It seems to be completely irrelevant to the question. (Although it might be useful for debugging)

In order to debug this issue, double check that the following are correct:

- host
- port
- Database name
- username
- password

Double check that you can actually access the server, e.g. by pinging it, or by using telnet to connect to the host/port.

If all this doesn't help, set a breakpoint at Util.java line 389 or in the try block before see, what actually is happening and failing.